# No visible interface for UIWebView declares a selector windowScriptObject

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, bridge

I am going to build a bridge between JavaScript and Objective-C; I looked into the apple documentation and several tutorials and I tried to call a objective-c method from JavaScript.
Actually I copy-pasted the code from here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html 
But I get this error: No visible interface for UIWebView declares a selector windowScriptObject. The method windowScriptObject is used to create an instance of WebScriptObject. So here is the code:

```
  BasicAddressBook *littleBlackBook = [BasicAddressBook addressBook];  
  id win = [self.webView windowScriptObject];
  [win setValue:littleBlackBook forKey:@"AddressBook"];
```

Comment: If you are doing for iOS then windowScriptObject is not available in iOS refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html
For Javascript and Objective-C communication you can use webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: delegate using all click event on [a=href]

Comment: mayur thank you for commenting my question. Well what could I do then?

Comment: Are developing any iOS mobile application or not? Can you provide the more detail about your use-case?